# Text file to python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a text file, which has structured data as shown below in it:

```
item {
  id: 1
  name: 'abc'
}
item {
  id: 2
  name: 'def'
}
```

What is the best way to convert this in a python dictionary with following structure?

```
{'abc': 1, 'def', 2}
```

Edit: Sorry for not posting my attempt right away:

```
def label_map_to_dict(path):
    file = open(path, 'r')
    ids = []
    labels = []
    for line in file:
        if 'id:' in line:
            ids.append(int(line.split(':')[1].strip()))
        if 'name:' in line:
            labels.append(line.split("'")[1])

    return dict(zip(labels, ids))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Look at JSON as an alternative to what you are doing right now.

Comment: Sorry for not posting my attempt.
I can do it by reading in the text file line by line and then extracting the information.
But since this structure is similar to JSON i thought there might be a cleaner way.
However json.load does not work.

Comment: It's not json, but if you have control over the generating program, it should be easily possible to generate json instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the file and find `id, name` pairs:

```
import re
file_data = [i.strip('\n').lstrip() for i in open('filename.txt')]
line_data = [[int(b) if b.isdigit() else b[1:-1] if b.startswith("'") else b for b in re.split(':\s*', i)] for i in file_data if re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+:\s', i)]
grouped_data = [line_data[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(line_data), 2)]
last_data = dict([[b[-1] for b in i][::-1] for i in grouped_data])
```

Output:

```
{'abc': 1, 'def': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Super minimal solution which I hacked together in my editor (no regex involved)

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    res: dict = {}
    lst_file = list(f)
    for i in range(0, len(lst_file), 4):
        key = lst_file[i+2].strip().replace('name: ', '').strip('\'')
        value = int(lst_file[i+1].strip().replace('id: ', ''))
        res[key] = value  # update your dictionary

    print(res)
```

you can also do the same with dict comprehension like so

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    lst_file = list(f)
    res = {lst_file[i+2].strip().replace('name: ', '').strip('\''): int(lst_file[i+1].strip().replace('id: ', '')) for i in range(0, len(lst_file), 4)}

    print(res)
```

Though, I have to admit, it is not as beautiful with all the subsequent string operations... however, given the sparse explanation, this should do the job!

Given your attempt so far, you could also mix our solutions which yields the following:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    res: dict = {}
    lst_file = list(f)
    for i in range(0, len(lst_file), 4):
        key = lst_file[i+2].split('\'')[1]
        value = int(lst_file[i+1].split(':')[1])
        res[key] = value  # update your dictionary

    print(res)
```

Feel free to the dict comprehension for this solution yourself. Hope it helps.